# Setting up a network printer on Kubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, kubuntu

I'm struggling to setup a network printer on Kubuntu. Ubuntu works 100%, but Kubuntu just does nothing

I did as below

From the Kubuntu desktop, Kmenu > System Settings > Printers > Add > Add Printer/

And then it just loads and loads and nothing happens.

Am I doing this the correct way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I presume from your instructions you are using Kubuntu with KDE 3.5.

Another way of configuring the local printers is to access the local CUPS web server on http://localhost:631/

This will allow you to add/remove printers in the same fashion as in KDE and also uses the CUPS backend which KDE does so any printers you configure here will show up in KDE applications.

Answer (score 1):

On my system i needed to install the 'system-config-printer-kde' package, because it was not installed by default.

```
sudo apt-get install system-config-printer-kde
```

After that, the printer configuration is found in:

Kmenu-> "Computer" Tab -> Settings -> Hardware -> Printers

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for this helpful page.
With a linux Ubuntu20 with KDE I had to use

```
sudo apt-get install system-config-printer
```

and then

```
sudo system-config-printer
```

otherwise the system settings as a normal user does not let us add the new printers.